# "The value provided in the parameter DATE is not valid for its type" - SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've encountered an error as follows in SSRS:
[image]

I would like to drillthrough 'card_uid' field (see picture below) from one report (named 'Pruchody karet') to another ('Karetni transakce') while handling CardUID parameter and DateFrom and DateTo parameters.
DateFrom/DateTo are set as a date type in both reports and in stored procedures created for the reports.
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What value are you putting in when you run the report?

Comment: 'dd-mm-yyyy' in SSRS but it does not matter, because VS always convert a date to that type, no matter what is supplied.